# getView() method CHANGE listview items positions

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with a checked textview and two textviews,however, my getView method keeps changing the listview items while scrolling, the values and checkbox states are both saved into sqlite database. I tried every possible solution and spent 4 hours trying to fix that.
Any help appreciated.The only solution that worked was setting convertview to null at beginning of getView() which lags the listview.

GOAL:to make listview display items properly without changing its positions randomly.

Final working code for anyone in need:

```
   @Override
public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    viewHolder = null;
    if(convertView == null){

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sin_item,null);
        viewHolder = new HolderCo();
        viewHolder.box = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.coco);
        viewHolder.subject = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.subject_com);
        viewHolder.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_co);




        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (HolderCo)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.position = position;


    viewHolder.box.setText(list.get(viewHolder.position).getWhats());
    viewHolder.subject.setText(list.get(viewHolder.position).getSubject());

    if(list.get(viewHolder.position).isSelected()) {
        viewHolder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        viewHolder.box.setChecked(true);
        viewHolder.box.setPaintFlags(viewHolder.box.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }else{
        viewHolder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        viewHolder.box.setChecked(false);
        viewHolder.box.setPaintFlags(viewHolder.box.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
    }

    if(dator.equals("d"))
        viewHolder.date.setText(list.get(viewHolder.position).getDay()+"/"+list.get(viewHolder.position).getMonth()+"/"+list.get(viewHolder.position).getYear());

    if(dator.equals("m"))
        viewHolder.date.setText(list.get(viewHolder.position).getMonth()+"/"+list.get(viewHolder.position).getDay()+"/"+list.get(viewHolder.position).getYear());



    if(dator.equals("y"))
        viewHolder.date.setText(list.get(viewHolder.position).getYear()+"/"+list.get(viewHolder.position).getMonth()+"/"+list.get(viewHolder.position).getDay());







    viewHolder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(buttonView.isChecked()) {
                list.get(position).setSelected(true);
                db.updateState(list.get(position),true);
                buttonView.setPaintFlags(buttonView.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getBoolean("add_mark_dialog",true))
                buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialoging(viewHolder.position);
                    }
                });

            }else{
                buttonView.setOnClickListener(null);
                list.get(position).setSelected(false);
                db.updateState(list.get(position), false);
                buttonView.setPaintFlags(buttonView.getPaintFlags()&(~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));

            }
        }
    });







    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what kind of problem you are having. However, try making viewHolder as a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this:

```
viewHolder.box.setTag(position);
viewHolder.date.setTag(position);
viewHolder.subject.setTag(position);
```

you set the tags to the views to the first position they were created with.
So when `getView()` is called with non-null `convertView` (previously recycled), the tags in its `viewHolder` still point to that position.

Move these `setTag()` calls outside `if()`, to set new position to recycled view.

BTW I would rather replace all this with

```java
viewHolder.position = position; // outside if()
```

and using it everywhere you use (Integer)x.getTag()

UPDATE: Also you have to do this:

```java
viewHolder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
```

before this:

```java
viewHolder.box.setChecked(...);
```

Because otherwise it can trigger previous listener which most likely you don't want.

Comment: that worked for saving positions but the checkboxes state are still changing

Comment: no that didn't work but I fixed the onCheckedChangeListener and it worked.

Comment: thanks for the help and I posted the final working code

Answer (score 1):

You're updating the view conditionally with `if` conditions. You need to provide corresponding `else` blocks where you reset the view to their default values.

For example,

```
if(dator.equals("d"))
    viewHolder.date.setText(...);

if(dator.equals("m"))
    viewHolder.date.setText(...);

if(dator.equals("y"))
    viewHolder.date.setText(...);
```

needs to be something like

```
if(dator.equals("d"))
    viewHolder.date.setText(...);

else if(dator.equals("m"))
    viewHolder.date.setText(...);

else if(dator.equals("y"))
    viewHolder.date.setText(...);

else
    viewHolder.date.setText("some default value");
```

Similarly reset defaults in `viewHolder.box.setPaintFlags()`.

The reason is that `ListView` views are recycled. Recycled views are not in their pristine state like they were immediately after inflation. Instead they will be in a state they were before they were recycled, possibly containing data from the list row previously using that view.

Comment: these are actually date formats that can be set in settings and it does have a default value.